# Get object value of Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, microsoft-graph-api

I have an object `$obj` like this (this is the `print_r` version of it):

```
Microsoft\Graph\Model\RecurrencePatternType Object
(
    [_value:Microsoft\Graph\Core\Enum:private] => weekly
)
```

I want to get the value "weekly".

This is what I tried:

```
$obj->{0};
$obj->getValue();
$obj->value();
$obj[0];
```

None of those worked. How can I get it?

Comment: According to [the code in their class](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Core/Enum.php), it should be `->value()`.

Comment: maybe you can't : http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php as it seems to be private. your object should provide a method to reach it.

Comment: can you share a bit more of you code ? the complete result of what you've got  with your 4 tests

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If you create an answer, I will accept it! thank you!

Comment: You say in your question that you've tried it and it didn't work though?

Answer (score 2):

As was correctly mentioned in comment since `RecurrencePatternType` is represented an `enum` type its value could be accessed via `value()` method.

**Example**

```
$event = $client->createRequest("GET", "/users/$userId/events/$eventId/")
    ->setReturnType(Event::class)
    ->execute();

$recurrence = $event->getRecurrence();
$patternTypeValue = $recurrence->getPattern()->getType()->value();
```